# How to add HTML code to textarea with push of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I'm building a webpage with a part were my girlfriend can easily upload blog posts and add photo's to that blog... I'm still working on a part for uploading new photo's to the server right from the blog upload.

Meanwhile I want to keep it as simple as possible for her. So I want to add a button to the page were she uploads the blog, that adds a basic img src html code part to the textarea in which she only has to edit the album and photo name.

After some research I found [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20110102112946/http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/):

But every time I add HTML code to this, it breaks the script.

Is there another way to have a button/link to add HTML code like img src stuff to a text area?

edit:

```js
function insertAtCaret(areaId,text) {
 var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
 var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
 var strPos = 0;
 var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? 
  "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false ) );
 if (br == "ie") { 
  txtarea.focus();
  var range = document.selection.createRange();
  range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
  strPos = range.text.length;
 }
 else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
 
 var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0,strPos);  
 var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos,txtarea.value.length); 
 txtarea.value=front+text+back;
 strPos = strPos + text.length;
 if (br == "ie") { 
  txtarea.focus();
  var range = document.selection.createRange();
  range.moveStart ('character', -txtarea.value.length);
  range.moveStart ('character', strPos);
  range.moveEnd ('character', 0);
  range.select();
 }
 else if (br == "ff") {
  txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
  txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
  txtarea.focus();
 }
 txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="messageBody"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Insert Smiley" 
onclick="insertAtCaret('<img src="image.jpg" height="150" width="260">',':)');" />
```

this is what I tried, but it didn't work ...

Comment: It would be much easier if you show us what you have so far

Comment: sorry, i added what i tried

Answer (score 0):

you could use some jquery and use the .text() function

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to add an image to a textarea .. why do it this way? A textarea returns a string, not binary in the form of a image. This is why it has the name *textarea*!

If you are going to upload posts to a blog with pictures, make it so you upload a picture to your server (this is the simplest way possible to do it, not the best), store the picture-name in a variable. Now when you click "post", store all your data in a Database.

When you want to show the picture, just get all the data related to the post to recive the image-location on the server.

I suggest looking into Firebase if you want to only work with JS. Firebase uses object oriented database. They have some tutorials and you can make a great blog with their tools. This can also be challenging if you have little experince with coding. Firebase is free to a certain limit ...

I suggest buying a physical book to learn JS properly, or on the subject you want to create. E.g. SQL, PHP, HTML etc.

### **Edit**

No, `<textarea>` does not support inline HTML. It supports CSS styles. I remember a long time ago when making an advanced calculator that I tried that, but it did not work. I ended up making my own editor, but this takes a lot of extra time and you need to know how to work with JS DOM Nodes.